# Issues with smooth histogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have a list of data, regarding particle size and I want to get a plot of the particle size distribution. For some reasons I can plot my data into an histogram using Histogram [data, Automatic, "CDF"], but when I try to use SmoothHistogram on the same data list, I get an error saying my data is not a suitable dataset. Does someone know why? If the dataset is suitable for Histogram, they are supposed to be also for SmoothHistogram according to Wolfram documentation.
Thanks for help
Francesca

Comment: Without the data it is difficult to assist.  Try checking that the data is all of the correct type with something like `DeleteDuplicates[Head /@ data]` or `Partition` the data into subsets and see if a particular subset fails.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the data, you are right. They were quite a lot anyway I will try with Partition, sounds quite smart, thanks!

Comment: Solved the issue. I imported a whole coloumn of data from an xlsx file and for some reasons the last element of the data set was """, and that caused issues with SmoothHistogram. I still don't really understand why it did not cause any issue in Histogram, but I guess since the code is working it doesn't matter that much.